# how to reset servlet data after a session end?

Tags: java, servlets

Suppose I have the following snippet of code:

```
    public class ApplyOfferCalculation extends HttpServlet {

        private RequestDispatcher rd;
        static int totaldiscount = 0;
        StringBuilder totalofferids = new StringBuilder();
        Map map = new HashMap();
        static int count = 0;
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
}
}
```

Now i want to reset the class level variables after a session end.
How to do it?

Comment: You should avoid defining non `final` fields at the Servlet level due to multi threading issues.

Comment: Why do you keep class level variables when you want to reset them? Just keep them local and pass them to other methods of necessary.

Comment: if you must have session-specific state then use the HttpSession, don't use servlet variables for this.

Answer (score 0):

Let the servlet container do its job, and do not try to store state in a Servlet. Using non-final static variables is highly discouragable.

If you need variables at the session level, then use the session for it, but keep the servlet free from stateful behaviour, as they are by definition stateless.